# Why I am getting np.nan==None true not false

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, data-science

[np.nan=None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15nKF.jpg)

I was watching a lecture on Querying a Series and when I am using this command I am getting true but in the video, it is showing false. Why so?

Comment: It should be ... np.NaN == None. Case sensitive

Comment: Actually @Anshul `np.NaN is np.nan`. But the double equals is important @shankar-dayal-mishra. Can you give us a bit more code to work with? We can't help debug your code if we don't know what it is. `np.nan == None` evaluates to False, so something is an issue here... Please see this post on [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially [creating a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the best quality answers!

Comment: I see ... my bad. Thanks!